# php readfile_chunked failing after 5 mintues

Tags: php, iis, download, readfile

This is what I've got at the moment:

```
$chunksize = 1024*4;
$h = fopen($file, 'rb');
set_time_limit(600);
while(!feof($h)){
    echo fread($h, $chunksize);
    flush();
}
fclose($h);
```

I've tried increasing the chunk size, I've tried resetting the timeout with every iteration, I've tried setting the timeout to zero (it was originally 5min), I even tried putting the flush() outside the loop to let its own buffer take care of it, and every single time the download dies at exactly 5 minutes in. Sometimes it's 50.2MB, sometimes it's 54.8 or anything in between, so I know it's not the file size. php_info() says the maximum time is 30seconds, so somehow I am able to increase it to 300 but that's it.

Is there something in IIS (server 2003) that could be overriding it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, Microsoft MVPs. Whenever they say something's impossible, you know it's just a matter of digging.

http://www.murraymoffatt.com/software-problem-0002.html

I was able to give this one specific file an unlimited run time without affecting the rest of the site.

EDIT:
Looks like those articles are starting to disappear.

Resetting FastCGI Timeout in IIS 5.0 (Win2K):

- Start the IIS management console (Start => Settings => Control Panel =>
  Administrative Tools => Internet Services Manager).
- In the tree on the left-hand side of the console you should see "Internet
  Information Services" at the very top, then below this the name of
  your computer. Right-click your computer name and select "Properties".
- Under "Master Properties" is a listbox; ensure that
  "WWW Service" is showing, then click the "Edit" button.
- Click on the "Home Directory" tab.
- Click on the "Configuration" button in the Application Settings area.
- Click on the "Process Options" tab.
- In the CGI Configurations area there is a "CGI script timeout" value
  specified in seconds. The default value is 300 seconds (5 minutes).
- Change this value to whatever you would like your timeout to be.
- Work your way out by clicking the "Ok" button on each window until you get
  right back to the IIS management console. Close the management
  console.
- Restart IIS by opening a command prompt (Start => Programs
  => Accessories => Command Prompt) and type the command: iisreset

IIS 5.1 (WinXP):

- Open IIS.
- Expand computer name.
- Right-click on "Web Sites" and choose Properties.
- Go to "Home Directory" tab.
- Click the "Configuration" button, brings up another window.
- Go to the "Process Options" tab.
- Set as your heart desires.
- Ok out.

Here's the instructions for IIS 6.0: http://www.iisadmin.co.uk/?p=7
but the download link for MetaEdit is broken, so try here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301386

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the EXACT same problem ..

For anyone looking, these solutions are specific to Windows IIS

I just went through 2 days of trying every possible config that had a setting of 300 seconds to try to fix the issue.

I changed the CGITimeout value in the metabase, but in my case the culprit turned out to be the FastCGI ini file (located in `c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\fcgiext.ini`)

There's a setting (in seconds):

```
ActivityTimeout=300
```

Change this value and restart IIS.